# How to attach an object to the NSCursor? OSX

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nscursor

I want to attach a WebView to the cursor when the user hovers a button. And remove it when the  mouse exits.
Even when the cursor moves inside the button I want to WebView to keep following the cursor.
Any ideas on how to perform this?

Here's an example on how it should be: 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so you have a NSButton ... subclass THAT so you attach a view:

```
@interface ButtonWithWebViewOnHover : NSButton
@property(strong) WebView *webView;
@end
```

override mouseEntered and mouseExited there and toggle hidden

...... wait.... we seem to be reinventing the wheel

---

use NSPopover (from apple directly, but not as graphically flexible as the next:)

or MAAttachedWindow (http://mattgemmell.com/2007/10/03/maattachedwindow-nswindow-subclass/)

Answer (score -1):

You can subclass WebView, and consider that to draw it this method is called:

```
- (void)drawRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
```

Ao if you call [super drawInRect: dirctyRect] in this method, the view will be normally drawn, otherwise nothing will be drawn.So you can see if the mouse is over the view and decide if to draw it or not.

To resize it, instead you can use this method:

```
- (void)setBounds:(NSRect)boundsRect;
```

To detect mouse events you shall implement methods like **mouseDown** (see [**NSResponder**](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSResponder_Class/Reference/Reference.html)) in your main view.

Comment: thanks for the answer, but xcode doesn't recognize `[super drawInRect:dirtyRect];` on my WebView subclass

Comment: because webview's dont draw.. the have webFrames (1-n] and THEY do the drawing -- I dont get why to subclass webview at all though :) ill write my ideas down

Comment: @PedroVieira, @Daji-Djan: Except WebViews are NSViews, and NSViews do respond to `drawRect:`. It may not do anything useful, since actual page drawing is done by subviews, but Xcode certainly should recognize it.